How to get device preferred orientations in Flutter
I am working on a package for a video player. I had this problem: I configured it to rotate to all orientations when the user navigates to the window I created. but I need to give the previous orientations when exiting the window. I couldn't find any information on how to get the orientation of the screen to be rotated.
I already have a slightly awkward solution. That is, I can adjust to those directions when I return to the back window by asking the developer what directions he wrote the appropriate code for. It would be nice to be able to find this out from SystemChrome or some other way without asking the developer.
Proposal
I want to get the orientations that the screen can rotate to by calling the SystemChrome.getPreferredOrientations function. if there is any other solution for this can you please explain where i can find this information?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
